# Enum with associated value does not conform to CaseIterable and throws error

Tags: ios, swift, enums

The following enum works fine without any error.

```
enum EnumOptions: CaseIterable {
        case none
        case mild
        case moderate
        case severe
        case unmeasurable
}
```

When I try to add an associated value to one of the cases, it throws the following error "Type 'EnumOptions' does not conform to protocol 'CaseIterable'. Do you want to add protocol stubs?"

```
enum OedemaOptions: CaseIterable {
        case none
        case mild
        case moderate
        case severe
        case unmeasurable(Int)
}
```

After adding stubs,

```
enum OedemaOptions: CaseIterable {
        typealias AllCases = <#type#>

        case none
        case mild
        case moderate
        case severe
        case unmeasurable(Int)
```

What should be filled up in the placeholder to make the Enum conform to CaseIterable, since there is only 1 case with associated value and not all the cases?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable): `The compiler can automatically provide an implementation of the CaseIterable requirements for any enumeration without associated values`. You basically need to provide your own implementation of `CaseIterable`

Answer (score 31):

Automatic synthesis does not work for enums with associated values. You need to provide a custom implementation of the allCases property. Try,

```swift
enum OedemaOptions: CaseIterable {
    static var allCases: [OedemaOptions] {
        return [.none, .mild, .moderate, .severe, .unmeasurable(-1)]
    }
    
    case none
    case mild
    case moderate
    case severe
    case unmeasurable(Int)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You forgot to account for all 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 `Int`s.

Also, each one is an `Option`, not an `Options`.

```swift
static var allCases: [OedemaOption] {
  [.none, .mild, .moderate, .severe]
  + (.min...(.max)).map(unmeasurable)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Compiler doesn't support automatic synthesis for *CaseIterable* in case with associated value(s).**

This is my alternative solution to *CaseIterable*

```swift
import Foundation

protocol CustomCaseIterable {
    associatedtype AllCustomCases: Hashable

    static var allCustomCases: [AllCustomCases: Self] { get }
}

extension CustomCaseIterable {
    init(_ string: String?, defaultCase: Self) {
        self = Self(string) ?? defaultCase
    }

    init?(_ string: String?) {
        guard
            let string = string,
            let caseValue = Self.allCustomCases.first(where: { "\($0.0)" == string })?.value
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self = caseValue
    }
}
```

**Example**

```swift
enum MyEnum {
    case one(Bool)
    case two(Int)
    case three(String)
    case four
}

extension MyEnum: CustomCaseIterable {
    static var allCustomCases: [String : Self] = [
        "one_true": .one(true),
        "two_zero": .two(.zero),
        "three_empty": .three(""),
        "four": .four
    ]
}

for (key, _) in MyEnum.allCustomCases {
    print(key)
}
```

**Extending that concept to RawRepresentable**

```swift
extension CustomCaseIterable where AllCustomCases: RawRepresentable {
    init(_ string: String?, defaultCase: Self) {
        self = Self(string) ?? defaultCase
    }

    init?(_ string: String?) {
        guard
            let string = string,
            let caseValue = Self.allCustomCases.first(where: { "\($0.0.rawValue)" == string })?.value
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self = caseValue
    }
}
```

**Example**

```swift
enum MapStyle {
    case primary(border: Bool)
    case secondary(border: Bool)
    case placeholder
}

enum JSONMapStyle: String, CaseIterable {
    case primary
    case primaryWithBorder = "PRIMARY_WITH_BORDER"
    case secondary
    case secondaryWithBorder = "SECONDARY_WITH_BORDER"
    case placeholder
}

extension MapStyle: CustomCaseIterable {
    static var allCustomCases: [JSONMapStyle: MapStyle] = [
        .primary: .primary(border: false),
        .primaryWithBorder: .primary(border: true),
        .secondary: .secondary(border: false),
        .secondaryWithBorder: .secondary(border: true),
        .placeholder: .placeholder
    ]
}


for (key, _) in MapStyle.allCustomCases {
    print(key.rawValue)
}
```