# How can I have associated value with CaseIterable enum?

Tags: swift

I want to use associated value with below case iterable enum. But when I use associated value it gives an error `Type 'DetailRow' does not conform to protocol 'CaseIterable'`. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
enum DetailRow: CaseIterable {
    case history
    case statements
    case visibility(Bool)
    case whatIsIn
    case faqs
    case terms
}
```

Comment: The problem is the `Bool`. `CaseIterable` gives you every case in the enum - but what would the value of the bool be? True or false? It can't tell, but what would you expect?

Comment: see [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-list-all-cases-in-an-enum-using-caseiterable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enum with associated value does not conform to CaseIterable and throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61757785/enum-with-associated-value-does-not-conform-to-caseiterable-and-throws-error)

Comment: @George_E what about `Void`? Swift should be able to tell that `Void` is always `()`

Comment: @0-1 A `Bool` must be either `true` or `false` - it cannot be `Void`/`()`.

Comment: @George_E I meant, what if the associated value was of type Void: `case visibility(Void)`? By your logic, Swift should know that `Void` is always `()`. But it doesn't. Swift is hard coded not to allow this: `Enum with raw type cannot have cases with arguments`

Comment: @0-1 `()` is a tuple. That’s also how you pass in arguments to a function. As for error, that is just stating an enumeration can’t have parameters _and_ a raw value. E.g. `case a(Int) = "hi"` is not allowed.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to implement it yourself when you have associated values:

```
enum DetailRow: CaseIterable {
   case history
   case statements
   case visibility(Bool)
   case whatIsIn
   case faqs
   case terms

   static let allCases: [DetailRow] = [
      .history, .statements, .visibility(true), .visibility(false), .whatIsIn, 
      .faqs, .terms
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Bool` isn't `CaseIterable` and automatic synthesis of nested case-iterability hasn't been implemented yet. You need to do it yourself.

```swift
extension Bool: CaseIterable {
  public static var allCases: [Self] { [false, true] }
}

extension DetailRow: CaseIterable {
  static var allCases: [Self] {
    [.history, .statements]
      + Bool.allCases.map(visibility)
      + [.whatIsIn, .faqs, .terms]
  }
}
```